# PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '?'

Tags: php, syntax-error

I have read a lot syntax error but seldom on the error of '?'

I also saw a few post that stated this might be due to old PHP version.

So my question is does PHP5.6 isn't enough? I am using Godaddy as my host and PHP5.6 is the highest they provide.

The full error description is:

> PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '?' in G:\PleskVhosts\tohokiwatch.com\httpdocs\cart\vendor\illuminate\database\Eloquent\Model.php on line 579

MyPHP page stated version 5.5.30:

[image: Myphpadmin page]

But my GoDaddy page stated version 5.6.30

Comment: My GoDaddy page screenshot:

[GoDaddy](https://imgur.com/WdxuGrR)

Comment: Where are you getting this error?

Comment: The error code .php file:

[Code](https://imgur.com/jQbJzlH)

Comment: Please post your code, especially around line 579 in the troubling file.

Comment: @TohJeuLun Wow, what is `??` suppose to do?

Comment: but its a file under the illuminate\database from github:

https://github.com/illuminate/database/blob/master/Eloquent/Model.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [null coalesce operator](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.null-coalesce-op), `??` does not exist in php 5.5 or 5.6, it was added in php 7.0

Comment: Does this mean I will need at least php 7 to work?

Comment: Yes. Or you will need to rewrite that piece of code to not use that particular operator.

Comment: I don't have the knowledge or ability to edit the code, I was originally following a tutorial from [codesource](https://www.codecourse.com/lessons/build-a-shopping-cart) on building a shopping cart but didn't expect to encounter this error @.@

Comment: Thank you Aron for the answer.